# Scale или Zoom по умочанию в jqvmap

Tags: javascript

http://www.jqvmap.com/ - есть карта с ее разновидностями и подразделами.
Хотелось бы устанавливать дефолтный (или начальный) scale и translate для transform. 
Реально ли это?
Если да, то как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

246 строка в файле jquery.vmap.js

```
this.rootGroup.setAttribute('transform', 'scale() translate()');
```

Вводите свои данные, если нужно. Может кому пригодится.

Comment: а может всё таки лучше вызвать функцию applyTransformParams() c нужными данными?